# How to identify clients from a pool of clients in the server - Design

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, network-programming

Okay, so I have a client/server library that I'm working. The server can accept multiple connections from clients. At every call to Accept(), if successful, the handle to the client's socket is pushed to a map, with a supposed unique ID as a key. So that when the server want to send a message to a specific client later on, it will find the client using this ID.

My question: What can be the unique ID for every client? IP address is not posssible as multiple clients can come from the same IP address. If not, can anyone suggest some other good design. Thanks

Illustration:

```
ClientSocket workerSock = Server.Accept();

Map.Add(workerSock);

       Map
____________________
|Key   | Value     |
|------------------|
| ?    |workerSock1| ------------------------ client application 1
|------------------|
| ?    |workerSock2| ------------------------ client application 2
|------------------|
| ?    |workerSock3| ------------------------ client application 3
--------------------
```

Scenario: Server wants to send to a specific client, so it has to have some ID.

Comment: You could do something as simple as providing integer handles back to your library's clients. Maintain an internal counter that increments on each successful connection and rolls over correctly. This will have some shortcomings, but is much more lightweight than using a truly 'correct' solution such as RFC 4122 UUIDs. Make sure your handle generator is threadsafe if you go this route!

Comment: The only unique way i can think of is adding port info too for the hash.But not sure how it will work in your overall scheme

Comment: Seems this is the most effective and simplest, Thanks @Ron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solved a similar problem when creating the network library [networkComms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net). Our solution was to keep track of peers by IPEndPoint ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx)), Guid ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey1zx63.aspx)) and connection types, e.g. TCP, UDP etc. The Guid are exchanged during the high-level connection handshake so that both ends are aware of the other.

Comment: This seems a good solution, I already implemented a simple integer count suggested by one above. But I'll be taking note of this, since most likely I'm going to update my implementation sooner or later, Thanks @MarcF

Comment: I should also add that originally we thought we could just get away with a simple identification system as well. This lead to ALL sorts of nightmares when it actually came to implementation and testing in scalable environments. Also if you thinks its appropriate please accept / up vote useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, `workerSock.GetHashCode()` would do?

Comment: This is one option, however, msdn states that it doesn't guarantee unique hash for every object, so I'm a little unconfident about it