# C# TCP - How to set a ID to a socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

i want to set a ID to every Socket .

At the moment i have this here:

```
Socket socket;
            try{socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);}
            catch (ArgumentException e) { WriteConsoleColor(new ColoredString(ConsoleColor.Red, "[ERROR] " + e));return; }
            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
            login_script.OnPlayerConnectToTCP(clientSockets.Count);
```

i set a ID with **clientSockets.Count** but i think that **not** the best way to **set a ID**.

Im also have a **OnPlayerDisconnectFromTCP(ID,reason);**

```
Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;            
if (current.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead)){
                if (current.Receive(recBuf, SocketFlags.Peek) == 0){
                    login_script.OnPlayerDisconnectFromTCP(0, "Leave");
                    return;
                }
            }else { WriteConsoleColor(new ColoredString(ConsoleColor.Red, String.Format("[Invalid Packet] User(ID:{0}) send a invalid Packet ({1})\n", "test", Packet))); }
```

Thats the problem there is no way to get the ID for **OnPlayerDisconnectFromTCP(ID,reason);**

*I hope you understand it and can help me :)*

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> i set a ID with clientSockets.Count but i think that not the best way to set a ID

Probably not. After all, what happens if a client connects (ID is 1), a second client connects (ID is 2), the first client disconnects, and then a third client connects (ID is 2, even though your second client with ID of 2 is still connected). That seems like a bad choice. :)

Depending on your needs, it might be enough to keep a counter (*not* the count of a collection), that you increment with each new client. Using an `int`, you can handle 4 billion clients that way before you need to even *worry* about duplicated client IDs. And assuming that's actually a concern, it's not too difficult to address. You can either choose to use a `long` instead (gives you about eighteen quintillion clients before wrapping around), or when you've come all the way back to `0` with an `int`, take that opportunity to reassign client IDs for all currently connected clients, starting with `0` again.

For security reasons, this is a poor choice if the client ID is exposed to potential attackers in ways that being able to predict a client ID would be bad. But in many cases, this wouldn't matter.

If you need the ID to be less predictable, there are other techniques. For example, use `Guid.NewGuid()`.

> there is no way to get the ID for OnPlayerDisconnectFromTCP(ID,reason);

If so, that'd be because you're using the API wrong. Rather than the `AsyncState` value being the `Socket` itself, it should be a data structure that describes your client, and which includes the `Socket` reference and the client ID or whatever other identifying information you want to include or need.

That way, when you complete an I/O operation, you do so with the full context of your client information, including whatever ID you need to pass to a method.

See also [How to identify clients from a pool of clients in the server - Design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15126428) for related discussion.

As long as I'm writing, I'll also strongly encourage you to get out of the habit of using things like `Poll()` and `SocketFlags.Peek`. .NET provides a very usable and scalable asynchronous API for I/O, which works *much* better than polling a socket. Learn to use it and your code will work much better.